# Accessing graphql resolver arguments from Apollo plugin

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm trying to add a plugin to my ApolloServer graphql API that logs the output of the endpoint, using an argument passed in as the key.

However when a query gets made, it looks like

```
query($x: String!, $y: String!, $z: String!) {
  foo(user: { a: $x, b: $y, c: $z }) {
    bar
  }
}
```

The plugin looks like

```
{
  requestDidStart() {
    return {
      willSendResponse({ response }: {response: GraphQLResponse }) {
        console.log(`user ${ARGS.A} has made a request`);
        console.log('response sent to user': response);
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried accessing the variables from the request, but given that the variables can use whatever name the client wants this seems like a dead end. Is there a better way to access `args` inside the plugin?

Comment: What exactly are you using for your server and API endpoints?

Comment: Using ApolloServer

Comment: What do you mean by "accessing `args.a` outside of the resolver"?

Comment: Edited -- I mean is there a way to get an object a la { a: "VALUE_A", b: "VALUE_B", c: "VALUE_C" } inside the plugin, which only has access to the `GraphQLContext`

Comment: Wouldn't `request.variables` give you just that?

Comment: request.variables gives you { x: "VALUE_A, y: "VALUE_B", z: "VALUE_C" }. x, y, z are supplied by the client so the keys to the object can be whatever the client decides.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can access your variables before reaching resolvers.

```
async requestDidStart() {
  return {
    async didResolveOperation({ operation, request, contextValue }) {
      console.log(request.variables)
      /*
        {
          a: "blabla",
          b: "blabla"
          .
          .
        }
      */   
    },
  };
},
```